# Are kotlin singleton objects recycled by the JVM?

Tags: kotlin, jvm

Will a singleton class created by the kotlin keyword object be reclaimed by the JVM?

```kotlin
object MySingleton
```

If `MySingleton` is never used, Does it keep taking up memory while the application is running?

Comment: If it is "never used", why did you declare it in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper I'm just giving an extreme example.

Comment: So what's a "less extreme" example? If you *do* use the object, then the GC can't just throw it away, can it?

Comment: If it is never referenced in the first place it won’t be instantiated. But once it is instantiated it will stay in memory until the application terminates. There’s no condition under which the runtime could determine that you will never use the reference again and therefore be able to free it.

Comment: @Sweeper As your example `less extreme example` does not apply to my problem. The example you gave applies to ordinary classes that are recycled by the JVM when not in use, which is not necessarily the mechanism of a singleton class.

Comment: @Tenfour04 by the way, if a top-level variable is declared, but never used, will it always occupy memory?
If it is used at first and not used later, will it eventually be reclaimed by the JVM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Preface:** This answer only talks about Kotlin when targeting the JVM.*

---

If `MySingleton` is never used, then it is never loaded, and thus never takes up any memory. However, if you're asking if the singleton will be garbage collected after some period of non-use (after it's been used at least once), then the answer is essentially no.

Let's say you have:

```kotlin
object MySingleton
```

Then this is what that `object` is compiled to:

```
Classfile [omitted]
  Last modified Mar 9, 2023; size 631 bytes
  SHA-256 checksum ea5757d5e8673ae4a7153fba4699771529e5db7a28a72c92378c21f6dc7fbc29
  Compiled from "MySingleton.kt"
public final class MySingleton
  minor version: 0
  major version: 63
  flags: (0x0031) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL, ACC_SUPER
  this_class: #2                          // MySingleton
  super_class: #4                         // java/lang/Object
  interfaces: 0, fields: 1, methods: 2, attributes: 2
Constant pool:
   #1 = Utf8               MySingleton
   #2 = Class              #1             // MySingleton
   #3 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #4 = Class              #3             // java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               <init>
   #6 = Utf8               ()V
   #7 = NameAndType        #5:#6          // "<init>":()V
   #8 = Methodref          #4.#7          // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #9 = Utf8               this
  #10 = Utf8               LMySingleton;
  #11 = Utf8               <clinit>
  #12 = Methodref          #2.#7          // MySingleton."<init>":()V
  #13 = Utf8               INSTANCE
  #14 = NameAndType        #13:#10        // INSTANCE:LMySingleton;
  #15 = Fieldref           #2.#14         // MySingleton.INSTANCE:LMySingleton;
  #16 = Utf8               Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;
  #17 = Utf8               Lkotlin/Metadata;
  #18 = Utf8               mv
  #19 = Integer            1
  #20 = Integer            8
  #21 = Integer            0
  #22 = Utf8               k
  #23 = Utf8               xi
  #24 = Integer            48
  #25 = Utf8               d1
  #26 = Utf8               \u0000\f\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0002\b╞\u0002\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0007\b\u0002ó\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002¿\u0006\u0003
  #27 = Utf8               d2
  #28 = Utf8
  #29 = Utf8               [omitted]
  #30 = Utf8               MySingleton.kt
  #31 = Utf8               RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
  #32 = Utf8               Code
  #33 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #34 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #35 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #36 = Utf8               RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
{
  public static final MySingleton INSTANCE;
    descriptor: LMySingleton;
    flags: (0x0019) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
    RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations:
      0: #16()
        org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

  private MySingleton();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0002) ACC_PRIVATE
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   LMySingleton;

  static {};
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0008) ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: new           #2                  // class MySingleton
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #12                 // Method "<init>":()V
         7: putstatic     #15                 // Field INSTANCE:LMySingleton;
        10: return
}
SourceFile: "MySingleton.kt"
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #17(#18=[I#19,I#20,I#21],#22=I#19,#23=I#24,#25=[s#26],#27=[s#10,s#28,s#6,s#29])
    kotlin.Metadata(
      mv=[1,8,0]
      k=1
      xi=48
      d1=["\u0000\f\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0002\b╞\u0002\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0007\b\u0002ó\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002¿\u0006\u0003"]
      d2=["LMySingleton;","","()V", "[omitted]"]
    )
```

As you can see, the instance of the singleton is held in a `public`, `static`, `final` field and that field is assigned when the class is initialized. Therefore, the instance of the singleton will not be garbage collected until and unless the `Class` object is garbage collected. And the `Class` object will not be garbage collected until and unless its associated `ClassLoader` is garbage collected.

But it's rare for a `ClassLoader` to be garbage collected. In fact, I'm pretty confident it never happens in "standard" applications. Keep in mind that if *any* class loaded by the class loader is still "in use", then the class loader is strongly referenced, and thus not eligible for garbage collection.

I suspect only in applications/frameworks/containers that manage their own class loaders, with the intention of letting them be garbage collected in certain scenarios, will you see a `ClassLoader` be garbage collected. Though it's very hard to ensure there are no strong references to a class loader on demand. *And even then, that assumes the garbage collector is allowed and/or mandated to collect classes and class loaders*. [See Holger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75692133/are-kotlin-singleton-objects-recycled-by-the-jvm/75692934?noredirect=1#comment133537644_75692934).

So, the instance of the singleton is overwhelmingly likely to be held in memory for the entirety of the application's lifetime. You should consider it a certainty.

Since [you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75692133/are-kotlin-singleton-objects-recycled-by-the-jvm/75692934?noredirect=1#comment133533246_75692133) about it, the same applies to top-level variables. If you have the following in a source file named `Foo.kt`:

```kotlin
val bar = Any()
```

Then this is what it's compiled to:

```
Classfile [omitted]
  Last modified Mar 10, 2023; size 629 bytes
  SHA-256 checksum 35d96f7a51c14816b96102d40d466d14904c19162b4797ef7cbc08333b70394c
  Compiled from "Foo.kt"
public final class FooKt
  minor version: 0
  major version: 63
  flags: (0x0031) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL, ACC_SUPER
  this_class: #2                          // FooKt
  super_class: #4                         // java/lang/Object
  interfaces: 0, fields: 1, methods: 2, attributes: 2
Constant pool:
   #1 = Utf8               FooKt
   #2 = Class              #1             // FooKt
   #3 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #4 = Class              #3             // java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               getBar
   #6 = Utf8               ()Ljava/lang/Object;
   #7 = Utf8               Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;
   #8 = Utf8               bar
   #9 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/Object;
  #10 = NameAndType        #8:#9          // bar:Ljava/lang/Object;
  #11 = Fieldref           #2.#10         // FooKt.bar:Ljava/lang/Object;
  #12 = Utf8               <clinit>
  #13 = Utf8               ()V
  #14 = Utf8               <init>
  #15 = NameAndType        #14:#13        // "<init>":()V
  #16 = Methodref          #4.#15         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #17 = Utf8               Lkotlin/Metadata;
  #18 = Utf8               mv
  #19 = Integer            1
  #20 = Integer            8
  #21 = Integer            0
  #22 = Utf8               k
  #23 = Integer            2
  #24 = Utf8               xi
  #25 = Integer            48
  #26 = Utf8               d1
  #27 = Utf8               \u0000\n\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0003\"\u0011\u0010\u0000\u001a\u00020\u0001ó\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0002\u0010\u0003¿\u0006\u0004
  #28 = Utf8               d2
  #29 = Utf8
  #30 = Utf8               [omitted]
  #31 = Utf8               Foo.kt
  #32 = Utf8               RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
  #33 = Utf8               Code
  #34 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #35 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #36 = Utf8               RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
{
  private static final java.lang.Object bar;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/Object;
    flags: (0x001a) ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
    RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations:
      0: #7()
        org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

  public static final java.lang.Object getBar();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    flags: (0x0019) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: getstatic     #11                 // Field bar:Ljava/lang/Object;
         3: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0
    RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations:
      0: #7()
        org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

  static {};
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0008) ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: new           #4                  // class java/lang/Object
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #16                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         7: putstatic     #11                 // Field bar:Ljava/lang/Object;
        10: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0
}
SourceFile: "Foo.kt"
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #17(#18=[I#19,I#20,I#21],#22=I#23,#24=I#25,#26=[s#27],#28=[s#8,s#29,s#5,s#6,s#30])
    kotlin.Metadata(
      mv=[1,8,0]
      k=2
      xi=48
      d1=["\u0000\n\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0003\"\u0011\u0010\u0000\u001a\u00020\u0001ó\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0002\u0010\u0003¿\u0006\u0004"]
      d2=["bar","","getBar","()Ljava/lang/Object;","[omitted]"]
    )
```

The top-level variable was compiled to a `private`, `static`, `final` field of a class named `FooKt`, and the field is assigned when the class is initialized. As the field is private in this case, you'll note there is a `public`, `static` getter method to access it. And as the field is static, the same reasoning from above regarding when and if it will be garbage collected applies.

Comment: Your suspicion is right. The specification even mentions explicitly that “[Classes and interfaces loaded by the bootstrap loader may not be unloaded.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7:~:text=Classes%20and%20interfaces%20loaded%20by%20the%20bootstrap%20loader%20may%20not%20be%20unloaded.)” as a consequence of the rules you described. Since the application class loader can be reached from a class loaded by the bootstrap loader (`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`), this applies to all “ordinary” application classes, loaded through class path or module path